# How to remove pc hostname from email message header

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I want to remove my desktop's host name from message headers

After browsing on some website, finally I can't find the article to fix this

[image: Picture 1]

In picture 1 we can see my desktop name and I want it to look like picture 2

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that may not appear in message headers at all; it’s just the reverse DNS entry for your IP address, and you can’t hide that - and while configuring it without a reverse entry may give you the blank result you’re asking for, it’s not actually hiding your identity at all - and it’s not something you should be trying to do anyway.